# Can't insert data in table with relationship (entity framework)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm working with the Entity Framework and I'm having a problem:

When I try to insert some data in a table it tells me that it's violating integrity of reference but the other table is normally populated and has the value i'm trying to insert.

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
pedido.Data = DateTime.Now;

db.AddToPedido(pedido);
db.SaveChanges();

EntityKey chave = db.CreateEntityKey("Pedido", pedido);
Itens_Pedido item = new Itens_Pedido();

item.Pedido_Id = Convert.ToInt32(chave.EntityKeyValues.First().Value);
item.Carta_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());                    
item.Quantidade = 1;
item.Foil = "N";

db.AddToItens_Pedido(item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what is going on.

If you have an identifying relationship between `Pedido` and `Iten_Pedido`

i.e. the Primary Key of `Iten_Pedido` is a compound and made up of two fields one of which is an FK back to Pedido (that would be the `Pedido_Id`) in your case, unfortunately you can't build that relationship using the `Pedido_Id` property you have to use the `Pedido` navigation property instead.

If you have the `Pedido` already in the context all you need to do is build the relationships as normal. If however it isn't int the context, which I suspect, and all you know is the key, then you have two options:
1) Query for it
2) Fabricate a stand-in entity and attach it (this is similar to a query in that it puts the entity in the ObjectContext in the unchanged state).

So the patterns are either:

```
//assuming the key of the Pedido is Id change as appropriate
Pedido pedido = ctx.Pedido.First( p => p.Id == XXX); 
item.Pedido = pedido;
...
ctx.AddToItens_Pedido(item);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido {Id = XXX};
ctx.AttachTo("Pedido", pedido);
item.Pedido = pedido;
...
ctx.AddToItens_Pedido(item);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

See [my tips series](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx) for more information, in particular [tip 9](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx)

Hope this helps

Alex